# how to setcap for a binary file in docker image

Tags: linux, docker, capability

I want to set capabilities for some binary files in my docker image so that i can execute them in a container with a non-root user, i have tried to setcap in my dockerfile:[dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1npg.png), then i built this image with docker build: [docker build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlYxY.png), but when i created a container with this image, i can not find any capability set for the file: [no capability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnfYk.png). Is this a docker bug? Or is there any other way to set capabilities for files in docker image?

Comment: An image can't force the operator to give it extra permissions, they have to be specified at `docker run` time.  Can you edit the question to include the actual `docker run` command you're using and the actual error you're getting (as text and not images; in the question and not behind links)?

Answer (score 2):

I take `cap_net_admin` and `ip` as an example.

In the Dockerfile below, `/bin/ip` have granted the `cap_net_admin` permition.

```
FROM debian

RUN useradd -m alice -s /bin/bash \
    && setcap cap_net_admin+ep /bin/ip

USER alice
CMD ["/bin/ip", "link", "show"]
```

But after built, it seems not working.

```
$ docker build -t cap .
$ docker run --rm cap
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: operation not permitted
```

That's because the Docker runtime limit the permition.
If you really want to do that, `--cap-add` is necessary.

```
$ docker run --rm --cap-add=cap_net_admin cap
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
43: eth0@if44: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

In K8s, you may need something like this:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: cap-test
    image: cap
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add: ["NET_ADMIN"]
```

#### References

- [Runtime privilege and Linux capabilities](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities)
- [Configure a Security Context for a Pod or Container | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/zh/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/)

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that do not setcap on your base image(parent Dockerfile)